# Stuck after trying to false check after getter method

Tags: java, setter, getter

So im stuck with my code here. Im supposed to use get and set method to give a person a name, a surname and year of birth. 
Here is the class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Person {

private int Birthyear;
private String Sname;
private String Name;

public Person() {
}

public Person(String n,String s,int b){
    Name = n;
    Sname = s;
    Birthyear = b;
}
public String getName (){
    return Name;
}
    public String getSname (){
    return Sname;
}
    public int getBirthyear (){
    return Birthyear;
}
```

This is the set code where i check the code for things like a name containing a number and if your birtyear is incorrect. This is also where i believe the problem is.

```
    public void setb(int b){

    while(b < 1899 || b >= 2016  ){
        System.out.print("Du existerar inte , försök igen: " );
            b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Checks if age is possible.
    }
    }
    public void setn(int n){

    while(Name.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
        System.out.print("Felaktigt namn, försök igen: " );
            n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Checks to see if there is any numbers in the name.      }
    }
    public void sets(int s){

    while(Sname.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
        System.out.print("Felaktigt namn, försök igen: " );
            s = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Checks so there is no numbers in the surname
    }
}
}
```

This is my main.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PersonUI {

public PersonUI() {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Skriv in ditt förnamn: " );
        String n = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.print(n); //Your name

    System.out.println(" Skriv in ditt efternamn: " );
        String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.print(n +" "+ s);//your surname

    System.out.println(" Skriv in ditt födelseår: " );
        int b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println(n +" "+ s +" "+ b);//date of birth

            Person p1 = new Person (n,s,b); //Name of person and date of birth
```

here is the get method

```
    System.out.print(p1.getName());
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(p1.getSname());
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(p1.getBirthyear());
    }
}
```

*I believe the code fails here*

```
    public void setb(int b){

    while(b < 1899 || b >= 2016  ){
        System.out.print("Du existerar inte , försök igen: " );
            b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Kollar ifall du har en ålder som fungerar.
    }
    }
    public void setn(int n){

    while(Name.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
        System.out.print("Felaktigt namn, försök igen: " );
            n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Kollar så att det inte finns siffror i namnet.
    }
    }
    public void sets(int s){

    while(Sname.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
        System.out.print("Felaktigt namn, försök igen: " );
            s = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); //Kollar så att det inte finns siffror i namnet.
    }
```

*or here*

```
  Person p1 = new Person (n,s,b); //Säger vad personen heter och när dne är född


    System.out.print(p1.getName());
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(p1.getSname());
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(p1.getBirthyear());
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem ? Can you explain ?

Comment: could you elaborate what the problem actually is?

Comment: sorry about that. The problem is that the false checking part isnt working. I can for example write in that my name is 12 @KevinEsche

Comment: Where do you use your actuall code to check the name year and sur name? Since you just call `new Person(n,s,b)`, it won´t check the values. in addition the methods to check the name and surname are looking weird (int as function method?) and they are not setting the name as far as i see. All in all i don´t see any starting point to help, since the code rather looks confusing.

Comment: Elaborate on which line you are seeing unexpected behaviour.In that way.people will be able to help.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta I have written where i believe the problem is.

Comment: @KevinEsche I dont really understand what you are saying. But i presume that new Person(n,s,b) is the problem by how you are saying it?

Comment: Can you trace the exact line of code where it fails?

Comment: @Marc you are assuming that the methods `setn..` are the fault for your problem, but they are never getting called from anywhere from what you have shown. In addition you are using this line `Person p1 = new Person (n,s,b);`. As you can see in your constructor for `Person`, it does no check whether it´s a valid name or surname or birthdate. The last thing that bothers me are the methods where you actually check the name, and the surname. They simply loop if the Name does contain a number, but you are inputting a new int from the console. (and i don´t understand the language).

Comment: @KevinEsche I have now translated the top part.

Comment: And from what you've said i assume i need to call upon the set method. how do i do that?

Comment: as i said, you never check the values, you simply assign them with `new Person (n,s,b);` judging the code you provided.

Comment: @KevinEsche Then i would like to aquire some help with calling the set methods. Not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i changed your code a little bit, it should be working like this

The methods to check the values are now static and do return a boolean to check if the are matching the correct input.

```
public class Person {

    private int Birthyear;
    private String Sname;
    private String Name;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String n, String s, int b) {
        Name = n;
        Sname = s;
        Birthyear = b;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return Sname;
    }

    public int getBirthyear() {
        return Birthyear;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setSName(String sName) {
        Sname = sName;
    }

    public void setBirthYear(int birthyear) {
        Birthyear = birthyear;
    }

    public static boolean setb(int b) {
        return !(b < 1899 || b >= 2016);
    }

    public static boolean setn(String n) {
        return !n.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }

    public static boolean sets(String s) {
        return !s.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }
}
```

The other class does simply use these static methods now to loop as long as the input is not matching your critera.
Also you don´t need to create a new Scanner object for each input, just create it once.

```
public class PersonUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n, s;
        int b;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Skriv in ditt förnamn: ");
            n = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(n); // Your name
        } while (!Person.setn(n));
        //
        do {
            System.out.println(" Skriv in ditt efternamn: ");
            s = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(n + " " + s);// your surname
        } while (!Person.sets(s));

        do {
            System.out.println(" Skriv in ditt födelseår: ");
            b = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(n + " " + s + " " + b);// date of birth
        } while (!Person.setb(b));

        Person p1 = new Person(n, s, b); // Name of person and date of birth
        System.out.print(p1.getName());
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(p1.getSname());
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(p1.getBirthyear());
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Person.sets() should also be called in setName() methods. Checking only when an object is created is fine, but the setter methods can set incorrect values to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setb(int b)
```

You can rename this method to something like

```
private static boolean checkB(int b)
```

Do this in the constructor: (you can do this in the setter methods as well, make seperate methods to validate your data)

```
public class Person{
int b;
public person(int b){
    if(checkB(b)){
        this.b = b;
    }
    else{
        //throw exception
    }
    }
private static boolean checkB(int b){
    return (b < 1899 || b >= 2016);
}
public void setB(int b){
    if(checkB(b)){
        b = b;
    }
    else{
        //throw exception
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public class Person {

    private int Birthyear;
    private String Sname;
    private String Name;

    public Person(String n, String s, int b) {
        if (!isBOk(b) || !isNOk(n) || !isSOk(s)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        Name = n;
        Sname = s;
        Birthyear = b;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return Sname;
    }

    public int getBirthyear() {
        return Birthyear;
    }

    private boolean isBOk(int b) {
        return (b >= 1899 || b < 2016);
    }

    private boolean isNOk(String n) {
        return n.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }

    private boolean isSOk(String s) {
        return s.matches(".*\\d+.*");
    }
}
```